# (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

yuz_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\mirac\\PycharmProjects\\YüzTanıma\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, img = cap.read()
yuzler = yuz_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in yuzler[0:kac_yuz_algilama]:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 230, 0), 2)
    yuz = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow("Pencere", img)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
[ERROR:0@0.016] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp (505) cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: 'C:\Users\mirac\PycharmProjects\YüzTanıma\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mirac\PycharmProjects\YüzTanıma\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    yuzler = yuz_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't think the problem is not related with path. Because I tried all of the ways. Can anyone help me?

I changed the place of .xml. I changed the path in python code. I uninstalled 3.11 and installed 3.6.

Comment: What is `ret` returned by `cap.read`?

Comment: What happens if you add `import os.path; print(os.path.isfile('C:\\Users\\mirac\\PycharmProjects\\YüzTanıma\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))` at the top?

Comment: You might be having problems with the character `ü` in your path. Try moving the `xml` file directly one level below your root directory.

Comment: @mkrieger1 if I add '''import os.path; print(os.path.isfile('C:\\Users\\mirac\\PycharmProjects\\YüzTanıma\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')) ''' it says 'True'